# Can a longbow be stored in a glove of storing?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Glove of storing states that

> The item can weigh no more than 20 pounds and must be able to be held in one hand

The longbow requires 2 hands to be USED, but it doesn't say it can't be held in one hand (And bows ARE held in a single hand while shooting. The other hand just pulls the string).

So can longbows be stored in a glove of storing?

Comment: Please avoid the *glove of storing* if at all possible; it's incredibly and stupidly overpriced. The *glove of the master strategist* is much, much better in every way, for a lower (fairer) price.

Comment: I'm using the Gloves of the Master Strategist. 3600 gold, works like the gloves of storing and gives you true strike 1x per day

Comment: Yay, glad to hear it.

Comment: @KRyan Where can I find Gloves of the Master Strategist? They don't seem to be in any of the books I already have, and I was unable to find them on d20pfsrd.com

Comment: @MatthewNajmon Page 71 of *Ghostwalk*. It wasn't updated by *Ghostwalk*'s *3.5* update.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Yes**, you can hold a longbow with only one hand, and can therefore store it in the glove. For that matter, two-handed weapons and most items used with two hands can be held in one. This is especially useful for arcane spellcasters that require an open hand to use somatic components.

Comment: Note that this is a general rule for all two-handed weapons, and freeing a hand by holding a two-hander in one is an important maneuver for, say, every mage with a staff.