# How to cheaply apply enhancement to thrown weapons?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

*Disclaimer: I asked [previously here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/120065/1355) the specific effects of the Returning weapon property; where HeyICanChan smashed what little hope I held to pieces.*

Using the *Quick Draw* feat, a character with N attacks may throw N different weapons in a single turn. Unless that character is a level 4 *Bloodstorm Blade*, however, they may only recover at most a handful of them for the next turn.

As a result, such a build goes through thrown weapons as an archer build goes through ammunition. For an archer build, a bow confers its enhancement bonuses and other enchantments unto the arrows it fires. For a throwing build...

Is there a *glove*, *gauntlet*, or any such item which could be used to allow enhancing and enchanting darts or shurikens *as they are thrown*, much like a bow enchants the arrows it fires?

And if there is not, would it game-breaking to create such a custom magic item... for, say, the same price as a bow with equivalent properties?

---

*Note: I could work 4 levels of Bloodstorm Blade in the build, at a cost, but the idea that a prestige class such as Master Thrower is near pointless without another prestige class does not sit well with me.*

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, no, there is no official way to do that.

As a source for this, I wrote a [shadowhunter homebrew class](http://minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=10673.msg176208#msg176208) that has a way to do this. The totem class feature lets the shadowhunter keep one weapon as a totem and then wield or throw non-magical weapons of the same sort and have those versions take on the magic of the totem. The wording on that particular ability got rather verbose (I could probably do a better job with it these days), but I did try to research for existing options to copy that wording from or to directly reference instead of having to come up with all that.

Answer (score 1):

### The closest I can find is the *Mind Blade Gauntlet* from the MIC

The Magic Item Compendium has a Mind Blade Gauntlet* (MIC, p.117), which grants a mind blade a weapon property. After a certain level, mind blades can be thrown with the *Throw mind blade* class feature.

In 3.5, a mind blade can only be acquired via one of two methods, the Soulknife base class in the Expanded Psionics Handbook or SRD, and the Athasian Soulknife prestige class (highly recommended and much better built than the base class) from the official 3.5 Dark Sun site Athas.org *Prestige Class Appendix 1* book. (Free download, co-owned with WotC, thus considered first party material.) The prestige class requires simply a BAB +3, Know:Psionics 4, and a power point reserve, so qualifying is fairly simple, even if you don't take other psionics classes.

---

Some people allow material from Dreamscarred Press in 3.5, which would give you additional options (such as feats) for acquiring the ability.

---

Perhaps you could work with your DM and create a variant magic/psionic item based on the *Mind Blade Gauntlet* which works with thrown items?

Comment: I think you are giving short shrift to the unique status of Athas.org—while they had a special deal with Wizards of the Coast, no WotC employee worked on any Athas.org material, and in many cases, it showed (with no comment on the Athasian soulknife since I am not familiar with it—but I’m familiar with other Athas.org material and I am not impressed with all of it).

Comment: Be that as it may, the site is (last I check a few months or so ago) still ran and owned by someone who is currently an employee at WotC, and the status was never rescinded. Until further update, it IS first party material for 3.5, for whatever that is worth, and until WotC issues an update. Same goes for Birthright, Planewalker, and the other official sites in the same situation as Athas. I too feel that the material could use some tweaking and attention in order to improve quality, and have actually acted on that in the past.